Accessing encrypted MS SQL Database using the decryption key
I am migrating an old ASP application (written in the 2000s) to a new platform and am struggling with the best way to export the data in an unencrypted form. I have access to the current working site including the underlying code and have the validationKey and decryptionKey, the website properly displays the unencrypted data
The database is Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU27-GDR) (KB5040948) - 15.0.4382.1 (X64)    Jul  1 2024 20:03:23 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ).
At the moment I'm just trying to write a query in Azure Data Studio that will output the data in clear. I can connect to the the db and run queries but the results are encrypted.
Most of my searching for a solution (which feels like it should be simple!) talks about certificates which I don't think is relevant here. I also looked for symmetric keys as per one post but this query returns no results.
SELECT name KeyName, 
    symmetric_key_id KeyID, 
    key_length KeyLength, 
    algorithm_desc KeyAlgorithm
FROM sys.symmetric_keys;

I found this page which seemed to have what I was looking for but the decrypted field is just all nulls.
USE mydb;  
-- Get the passphrase from the user.  
DECLARE @PassphraseEnteredByUser NVARCHAR(128);  
SET @PassphraseEnteredByUser   
= 'mydecryptphase';  
  
-- Decrypt the encrypted record.  
SELECT Title, 
    CONVERT(varchar,  
    DecryptByPassphrase(@PassphraseEnteredByUser, FirstName, 1 ))  
    AS 'Decrypted Name' FROM dbo.contact  ;  
GO 


Given the age of the application/database (you said it was built in the 2000's), I think perhaps the encryption/decryption is done by the app itself and the database just stores the binary encrypted form.  The TSQL you have listed is for Always Encrypted, which first came out in 2016 and is unlikely to be relevant.  You need to find out where the decryption is happening (in the application layer or in the SQL layer) before proceeding.

Thanks, I did wonder that - will trawl through the code next.

@Jonathan Fite, correction, TSQL from examples has nothing to do with Always Encrypted. Moreover, it mixed two different approaches: the first is ENCRYPTBYKEY and the second is ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE. However I agree with idea of encryption is probably handled by client app.

Agreed. Those functions were introduced in 2005. If the app is pre-2005, then it is done at app layer.

The comments here led me to investigate the application side, I post here my results as they may help someone else.
The application is written in C#5 and uses a "symmetric encryption algorithm" (Rijndael/AES) to encrypt the string before storing it in the database.
I therefore had to extract the data from the database then use the application's decrypt method to decrypt it.
